# Can i use different timer channels when other channels (of the same timer) have i2c alternate function

Tags: c, timer, embedded, i2c, pwm

My embedded device has i2c on the following pins

```
GPIO_2 => GPT0_CH2 => configured as i2c SDA
GPIO_3 => GPT0_CH3 => configured as i2c SCL
```

and i've set up the other channels as

```
GPIO_0 => GPT0_CH0 => configured as PWM Led
GPIO_1 => GPT0_CH1 => configured as PWM Fan
```

Can the following configuration work?

The PWM is running at 2khz with duty cycle from 0% to 100%.

Will it have any impact on the i2c behaviour?

I'm expecting they are using the same GPT so changing frequency leads to a disaster?

Comment: The channels are usually unrelated, but this does depend on the peripheral settings. For example, some PWM settings can use multiple timers. My main question back to you would be why are you using a timer peripheral for I2C?

Comment: Just what is an "embedded device"? This question isn't answerable without knowing exactly which MCU that is used. And if your question is about EMC concerns, you should post at https://electronics.stackexchange.com instead.

Comment: @EdKing I'm not using a GPT to create an i2c, i just assumed that since i2c pins are all (generally) on a GPT peripheral they would use the GPT itself.
Can you confirm me that if i use CH2 for a purpose then CH3/4/5 are generally unrelated?

Comment: No, I can't confirm, but generally channels are unrelated.
I2C pins are not generally on (share) a timer peripheral, it depends entirely on the IO mapping of the MCU. It reads like you're confused about the operation of I2C.

Comment: As you have configured it that way surely you can answer the question "does it work" yourself!?  The answer in any case surely lies in the user manual for the part in question (which remains a mystery to us!)

Answer (score 0):

The PWM and the I2C module are connected to the GPIO output via an multiplexer. By configuring related registers in your microcontroller you can decide which output will be passed through to the GPIO. This block diagram shows **a very simplified** overview of the relations between peripheral modules, multiplexer and output:

[image]

By setting `SEL` to `0`or `1` either `IN0` or `IN1` will be passed through to the GPIO pin.

So the answer is: No, your setting for the PWM frequency will not have any impacts on I2C behaviour.

Comment: That seems legit, i'll accept you answer as soon as i'm able to try it out

Comment: Your diagram does not appear to be what the question describes, the description in the question is entirely unclear, and you do not even know what the MCU part is, so being keen to help is admirable, but this seems unlikely to be "the answer" as the question is unanswerable.

Comment: I answered the question how I understood it.